# GTK theming as in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: gtk

In Ubuntu Software Center I can see a background image and some icons which really render it beautiful. I want to do the same with my GTK applications so would you please tell me how did they do that ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was probably done with [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/).